# Vaadin How to reset TextArea value in Vaadin if validation on save failed

Tags: java, textarea, vaadin, textfield

How do I reset the value of a `TextArea` in Vaadin if the validation on save action failed. My code below:

1. it gives text area with text "A" retrieved from DB;
2. then I want to change text area  to text "B"
3. when validation on "B" hass failed and B is not saved to DB I expect to see text "A" in the text area but text "B" is displayed.

---

```
VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
TextArea text = new TextArea();   
text.setValue(controller.getFile().getName());    
text.setRequired(true);
Button save = new Button("Save", event -> {
            try {
              newName.validate();
               if (controller.getFile().updateName((text.getValue()))){
                     close();                     
               } else{
                   System.out.println("WRONG TEXT!");
               }    
            } catch (Validator.InvalidValueException ex) {
                text.setValidationVisible(true);    
            }
        });
        save.setSizeFull();
        content.addComponent(text);
        content.addComponent(save);
        setContent(content);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just plain Java in updateName() method:

```
public boolean updateName(String newName) {
        if (controller.getFile()!=null) {
            controller.saveFileName(controller.getFile());
            file.setName(newName);   // mistake was in this line.
          }                 
           return false;
    }
```